# Is there a way to find exact match and not substring match using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

given a sentence like this `Sent = "ball bearing robertshaw 20"` i am using a pattern `"roberts|robertshaw"` and would like the result to be `"robertshaw"` but getting only `"roberts"`

```
import re
sent = "ball bearing robertshaw 20"
pattrn = "roberts|robertshaw"

re.findall(pattrn,sent)
```

Comment: Do you mean like whole words? If that is what you want then you can use word boundaries `\broberts\b|\brobertshaw\b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word boundaries:

`\b(?:roberts|robertshaw)\b`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1RiXZW/4)